# "Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Float64,2} to an object of type Array{Float64,13}

Tags: arrays, constructor, julia, matpower

I'm getting the following error

```
ERROR: "Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Float64,2} to an object of type #Array{Float64,13} This may have arisen from a call to the constructor #Array{Float64,13}(...), since type constructors
```

Here is the code that I tried:

```
type buscase
baseMVA::Float64
bus::Array{Float64,13}
gen::Array{Float64,21}
branch::Array{Float64,13}
end

mpc=buscase(100.00,
[1  2   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   230 1   1.1 0.9;
2   1   300 98.61   0   0   1   1   0   230 1   1.1 0.9;
3   2   300 98.61   0   0   1   1   0   230 1   1.1 0.9;
4   3   400 131.47  0   0   1   1   0   230 1   1.1 0.9;
5   2   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   230 1   1.1 0.9;],

[1  40  0   30  -30 1   100 1   40  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;
1   170 0   127.5   -127.5  1   100 1   170 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;
3   323.49  0   390 -390    1   100 1   520 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;
4   0   0   150 -150    1   100 1   200 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;
5   466.51  0   450 -450    1   100 1   600 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0;],

[1  2   0.00281 0.0281  0.00712 400 400 400 0   0   1   -360    360;
1   4   0.00304 0.0304  0.00658 0   0   0   0   0   1   -360    360;
1   5   0.00064 0.0064  0.03126 0   0   0   0   0   1   -360    360;
2   3   0.00108 0.0108  0.01852 0   0   0   0   0   1   -360    360;
3   4   0.00297 0.0297  0.00674 0   0   0   0   0   1   -360    360;
4   5   0.00297 0.0297  0.00674 240 240 240 0   0   1   -360    360;]
)
```

Comment: The second parameter between braces control the dimension and not the size of the array. To enforce array size, you can use an explicit constructor for your type. See here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175581/declare-the-size-of-an-array-attribute-in-a-type-definition

Comment: Th negative point on your question is because you put the error but not the code that generate the error.
If you want people to help you, you should put them in the conditions to replicate your situation, e.g. writing a minimal example that leads to your error or problem.

Comment: I gave you an answer but please edit your question so it is more readable for others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should define your structure

```
struct buscase
   baseMVA::Float64
   bus::Array{Float64,2}
   gen::Array{Float64,2}
   branch::Array{Float64,2}
end
```

Now your command `mpc=buscase(100.00, ....` will work

Like it was said the number in the `Array` definition denotes the number of parameters.

you could also use the `Matrix` type which is a shorter form for `Array{T,2}`:

```
struct buscase
   baseMVA::Float64
   bus::Matrix{Float64}
   gen::Matrix{Float64}
   branch::Matrix{Float64}
end
```

Last but not least if you wanted to have a fixed size for an array you should look at `StaticArrays.jl` package. However, the usage of this package is recommended for arrays up to 10-20 elements (depending on observed performance gain).